# migrating imap using imapsync

Tags: centos, email, email-server, migration, imapsync

i have 2 centos vps, dovecot, sendmail and ssl are installed on both servers, i want to migrate the mail server from `oldserver` to `newserver` so i installed imapsync on both servers. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapsync), I use the ip address of my servers, instead of the hostname.

When i do:

```
imapsync --oldserverip --user1 Me@example.com --passfile1 /etc/secret2 --newserverip --user2 me@example.com --passfile2 /etc/secret2
```

I get:

```
Temp directory is /tmp PID file is /tmp/imapsync.pid Modules version
list: Mail::IMAPClient     3.32 IO::Socket           1.29
IO::Socket::INET     1.29 IO::Socket::SSL      ? Digest::MD5         
2.36 Digest::HMAC_MD5     1.01 Term::ReadKey        2.30 Authen::NTLM         1.09

Info: turned ON syncinternaldates, will set the internal dates
(arrival dates) on host2 same as host1. Info: will try to use LOGIN
authentication on host1 Info: will try to use LOGIN authentication on
host2 Host1: imap server [old server ip] port [143] user
[me@example.com] Host2: imap server [new server ip] port [143] user
[me@example.com] Failure: can not open imap connection on
[old server ip] with user [me@example.com]: IO::Socket::INET:
connect: Connection refused
```

If i use `ssl1` option and specify which port i want to use i get this error:

> dualvar is only available with the XS version of Scalar::Util at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 38 BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 38. Compilation
>   failed in require at /usr/bin/imapsync line 3900.

I think there are missing dependencies as mentioned [here](http://www.zimbra.com/forums/migration/24992-solved-imapsync-imap-over-ssl.html)

- Mail-IMAPClient
- Net-SSLeay
- IO-Socket-SSL
- Date-Manip
- Term::ReadKey
- Parse-RecDescent
- Net-IDN-Encode
- Unicode-Stringprep
- Digest-MD5

But i don't know how to install them, they are not available using `yum`

Comment: Check if 143 is the right port. Eg. if you use TLS/SSL, you should use port number 993: `--ssl1` / `--tls1` and `--port1 993`

Comment: @stderr please read my edit

Answer (score 2):

a) For the "Connection refused" issue, change dovecot configuration to allow IMAP on the default port 143.

b) For the "dualvar is only available" issue see:
https://alexcline.net/2012/02/02/message-dualvar-is-only-available-with-the-xs-version-of-scalarutil-error-in-centos-5/

From dovecot to dovecot rsync will be faster, by a magnitude of 100.

c) For the modules dependencies read
http://imapsync.lamiral.info/INSTALL
there are the package names to use with yum.

```
yum install perl-Mail-IMAPClient       # Mail::IMAPClient
yum install "perl(Term::ReadKey)"      # Term::ReadKey
yum install "perl(Authen::NTLM)"       # Authen::NTLM
yum install perl-Data-Uniqid           # Data::Uniqid
yum install perl-File-Copy-Recursive   # File::Copy::Recursive
yum install perl-IO-Tee                # IO::Tee
```

Comment: how to migrate email users and mails using rsync?

Answer (score 0):

For the missing dependencies, you will need to use a 3rd party repositories such as [repoforge](http://repoforge.org/) or [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: epel is installed and i can't find the requirements using epel