# Does rsync migrate mail servers?

Tags: centos, email, email-server, rsync, dovecot

imapsync gives errors, here's [my previous post.](https://serverfault.com/questions/487594/migrating-imap-using-imapsync)

So is it possible to migrate mail servers (dovecot to dovecot) using rsync? If not, then how to migrate mail servers? Is there any tools other than imapsync?

**EDIT**

I didn't want to use rsync, if you read my previous post, a user called **Gilles LAMIRAL** said:

`From dovecot to dovecot rsync will be faster, by a magnitude of 100.`

I asked him: how to migrate email users and mails using rsync? He didn't reply, so I asked you.

Comment: Where are your mail directories stored? What format (Mbox|Maildir) are your mails in? Are you using NFS, mysql for the user authentication?

Comment: I... I don't even... I mean... just... no.  Don't try to migrate mail servers with rsync.

Comment: I actually migrated user mail from maildir to maildir between dovecot servers with rsync, but as voretaq7 stated, it was something I had tested and planned.

Comment: @HopelessN00b so you said `For what it's worth, migrating the mail data is sometimes done with rsync, but that's not the same thing as migrating a mail sever.` What do you think i should use?

Comment: @NickW what would happen, if rsync mygration didn't work?

Comment: You find another way, rsync is only a part of the process, you will use it to move user mail (and the storage structure) from A to B. The authentication, configuration and other pieces will use other tools.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` does not "migrate" anything. It simply copies files from A to B.  From the man page:

> rsync is a program that behaves in much the same way that rcp does, but has many more options and uses  the  rsync  remote-update  protocol  to greatly  speed  up  file  transfers  when the destination file is being updated.

So the answer to your question is "It is possible to migrate mail servers using `rsync`, if and only if it is possible to do so by copying files from A to B." -- If you aren't sure if that is the case, test in a lab before you try it in production.

Comment: For what it's worth, migrating the mail data is sometimes done with rsync, but that's not the same thing as migrating a mail sever.

Comment: I'll try using rsync but if rsync doesn't migrate, what's the right tool then?

Comment: @Fischer The right tools are time, a thorough understanding of your mail infrastructure, and good Unix skills (possibly including good DB skills) -- A mail server is not a lightbulb, and because email is almost always "business critical" the migration is something that requires substantial thought and planning (possibly including a test environment if this is your first migration).